# link and style tags in css

Tags: html, css

so I wanted to link a css page to my html but this does not work for me. Now I put my css into html with the style tag and it isn´t working either.

What I´m making wrong here.

Thanks in advance. :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="BHP.css" > -->
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url("website_start_powder.jpg");
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <div id="start_picture">
                <img src="website_start_powder.jpg" alt="powder">
            </div> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The comments are for the question purpose or are you really using the commented blocks in the code. Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp. Anything in comment is usually left out during the rendering of HTML

Comment: Your body needs a height

Comment: hi, so i just left the comments there for showing you, that i wanted to link my html to css but i know, that it does not effect my code... :)

Comment: @RichardHpa its working now but why cant ´t i set my height to 100% or auto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pay attention to your folder structure.

If you put the image file at the same level then it will run.

If you put it in the image folder then you can use the following code:

```
body
        {
            background-image: url("image/website_start_powder.jpg");
        }
```

basically you have to put and call the image file correctly..

Answer (score 0):

Your body must have content to let background be filled. So I set it a height to let background show. Click `Run code snippet` to see demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="BHP.css" > -->
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/hand-painted-watercolor-background-with-sky-clouds-shape_24972-1095.jpg");
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="height: 100px">
  <!-- <div id="start_picture">
                <img src="website_start_powder.jpg" alt="powder">
            </div> -->
</body>

</html>
```